# How to use existing aws s3 Bucket Using Flutter

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

my backend developer already creat a bucket on AWS s3 but when I run amplify add storage it creates a new bucket.
the official document is said

"An existing Amazon S3 bucket can be used with the Amplify Libraries by referencing it in your amplifyconfiguration.dart file."

```
  const amplifyconfig = ''' {
  "UserAgent": "aws-amplify-cli/2.0",
  "Version": "1.0",
  "storage": {
    "plugins": {
      "awsS3StoragePlugin": {
        "bucket": "[BUCKET NAME]",
        "region": "[REGION]"
      }
    }
  }
    }''';
```

which is not working

So how do I configure an existing bucket using flutter?

Comment: Did you figure this out?